# Delete item from Object, based on value

Tags: javascript, object-detection

I have below structure:

```
var value = 4;
```

Object value look like below image (console.log)

[image]

I want to delete entire row when **value** matches player_id.
I am using below, but look like it is not able to delete entire row (as I can see **'0: Object'** even after deletion.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].player_id === value) {
        delete obj[key];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the object in text notation (object literal), not as image.

Comment: Just FYI, your `obj` is an array. Use `splice(index, 1)`

Comment: you can use unshift() method

Comment: obj.indexOf(value) returns -1 always.

Comment: @NiteshKumar indexOf will return first matching value. If you are on ES6, you can use `array.findIndex()`

Comment: hint: `4 === "4"` returns false. aaaaand don't delete indices of Arrays, create a new Array containing only the values you need aka [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `delete` on array element, it is replaced by `undefined`. Correct way to delete element from array is to use `array.splice()`

#### Delete

```js
var obj = [{
  player_id: 1,
  team_id: 2
}, {
  player_id: 2,
  team_id: 2
}, {
  player_id: 3,
  team_id: 1
}, {
  player_id: 4,
  team_id: 1
}]

var value = 4;

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].player_id === value) {
        delete obj[key];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(obj)
```

#### Array.splice

```js
var obj = [{
  player_id: 1,
  team_id: 2
}, {
  player_id: 2,
  team_id: 2
}, {
  player_id: 3,
  team_id: 1
}, {
  player_id: 4,
  team_id: 1
}]

var value = 4;

for (var i =0; i< obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].player_id === value) {
        obj.splice(i,1)
        break;
    }
}
console.log(obj)
```

Also, `for..in` is for objects. You should use `for` or any other array function to loop over arrays.

#### Array.findIndex

```js
var obj = [{
  player_id: 1,
  team_id: 2
}, {
  player_id: 2,
  team_id: 2
}, {
  player_id: 3,
  team_id: 1
}, {
  player_id: 4,
  team_id: 1
}]

var value = 4;

var index = obj.findIndex(x=>x.player_id === value);
obj.splice(index,1)
console.log(obj)
```

**Note:** `array.findIndex` is a part of ES6 and will have compatibility issue. Please refer them before using.

Comment: obj.splice worked for me. Thank you very much Rajesh.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you needed

```js
var value = 4;

var arr = [
  {player_id: '11', team_id: '1'},
  {player_id: '4', team_id: '2'},
  {player_id: '10', team_id: '1'}
];


arr = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.player_id != value;
})

console.log(arr)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just a pointer, `filter` is more suited when you want another array. Not assigning and not returning will make it similar to `forEach` and you should use it.

Comment: @Mr.7, that's an awful way to approach that, not only abusing filter as forEach, but also a (potentially) repeated mutation of the Array you're iterating *(and the iterator itself has no clue of that)*, and all that just to generate a subset. use filter like this: `var subset = arr.filter(function(item){ return item.player_id !== "4" })`. and if the asker really wants to replace the original Array: `arr = arr.filter(...)`